Failed to add reference to 'XYZ', please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

When installing my nuget package from Nuget.Org (not sure if package source relevant), on my project I get this error:
Failed to add reference to 'XYZ', please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

It does not have an associated error code (example: NU5100).
Error happens specifically when installing the package on projects that target .net framework (tested on Framework 3.5 and 4.6), but does not happen on .Net8 projects.
The nuget targets .Net Framework 3.5, and if you want to take a look at the nuget itself, you can find it here.
the XYZ in the error message is CelikApi32 (an unmanaged dll) which is supposed to be distributed with it (there is also CelikApi64, but for now no error shows up for it).
Also, for now i can add <PackageReference Include="DirectCelik" Version="1.0.1" /> to the .csproj to solve the issue, but thats not a long term solution for a public package.
